# vue: Downloading excel files using node-xlsx

Tags: excel, database, vue.js, export, xlsx

I am very new to programming and working on a web project.
I used **node-xlsx** make **a button that export excel data**.
But I got an error "**Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'utils')**".

I think not many people are having the same problem.
It will be grateful if someone advice me solutions.

**My template only contains a button.**

```
<template>
  <v-card class="custm">
<v-btn @click="excelDown">excel</v-btn>
  </v-card>      
</template>
```

**My Data: See bottom**

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import XLSX from 'xlsx';

public incomeLogData = new Array<IncomeLog>();

  get IncomeLogList() {
    return this.incomeLogData;
  } 

  mounted() {
    this.setData();
  }

  setData() {
    //  header
    this.headers = [
      {
        text: this.$t("income.item06").toString(),
        align: "center",
        sortable: false,
        value: "userID"
      },
      {
        text: this.$t("income.item07").toString(),
        align: "end",
        sortable: false,
        value: "nickname"
      },
      {
        text: this.$t("income.item08").toString(),
        align: "end",
        sortable: false,
        value: "money"
      },
      {
        text: this.$t("income.item09").toString(),
        align: "end",
        sortable: false,
        value: "exp"
      }     
    ];

    // Dummy Data
    this.incomeLogData = [
      {
      "userID":"ACEJTH1",
      "nickname":"aceth1",
      "money":2000,
      "exp":8000,
      },
      {
      "userID":"aceSK1",
      "nickname":"acesk1",
      "money":2000,
      "exp":8000,
      }
    ];

// get excel button
  excelDown() {
      const dataWS = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.incomeLogData); 
      const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
      XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, dataWS, 'nameData');
      XLSX.writeFile(wb, 'example.xlsx');
  }
}
</script>
```

**And I attached my dev tool error.**
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rEL1.png

Answer (score 0):

I had this trouble with the 0.18.5 version. Uninstall an rollback to version 0.17.3. Everything worked fine!